# Sequelize adds column that does not exist anymore on creation

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize-typescript

I'm using sequelize to create tables on a node Typescript and postgres architecture.
The model i'm trying to create (questionnaire_subsection) used to have a property questionnaire_section_id that is a foreign key to another table but i removed it in choice of a relation table.

Problem is, now it tries to add it anyway on create :

```
await QuestionnaireSubsection.create({
            ordering: 1
        });
```

```
routine: 'errorMissingColumn',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO "public"."questionnaire_subsections" ("questionnaire_subsection_id","ordering","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING "questionnaire_subsection_id","ordering","created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","questionnaire_section_id";',
    parameters: [
      1,
      '2023-02-22 14:26:00.785 +00:00',
      '2023-02-22 14:26:00.785 +00:00'
    ]
  },
```

I checked and the table does not have the property anymore, the interface and models also don't have this property. I don't know where it is getting it, and why it is putting it at the end of the query like that. If it were still in the model it should be right after/before ordering.

here is a simplified version of my interface, i just removed translations

```
interface QuestionnaireSubsectionBaseInterface {
    questionnaireSubsectionId: number;
}

export interface QuestionnaireSubsectionCreateAttributes {
    ordering: number
}

export interface QuestionnaireSubsectionInterface extends QuestionnaireSubsectionBaseInterface, QuestionnaireSubsectionCreateAttributes, BaseModelInterface {}
```

base model interfaces only adds the timestamps and history

I simplified everything to the bare minimum and it still gives me the same error.
I cleared the database multiple time and even tried restarting vs code, just in case it was a weird cache error

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was an association remaining somewhere that still used the foreign key. I removed it and all went according to plan.